# Texas Hold Em: How did I lose this hand?

Tags: texas-hold-em

The board: Kclub, 5club, 2hearts, 3diamonds, 8diamonds.

Opponent: Adiamond, Jdiamond

Mine: Qdiamond, Kheart

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you misread the board? Chances are that three diamonds dropped on the board to give your opponent a flush with their suited hand (A⋄J⋄8⋄3⋄2⋄), or that they actually had A⋄4⋄, not A⋄J⋄, and hit the A⋄2♥3⋄4⋄5♣ straight.

Currently, your hand is K♣K♥Q⋄8⋄5♣ (One Pair on Kings, Queen Kicker)

And your opponent has A⋄K♣J⋄8⋄5♣ (High Card on Ace).

One Pair is better than High Card, so you win.

Answer (score -1):

I thought so too, but here’s the screenshoot.[image]

Comment: which hand is yours

Comment: I have the King and Queen. Yeah, I’m thinking malfunction too but just wanted to make sure. Thank you!

Comment: Or maybe you mistakenly clicked the "fold" button?

Answer (score -1):

there seems to be a malfunction, you should contact tech support and ask them to make it right